# How to understand "grep --color [Cat] <<<"nixCraft""?

Tags: bash

I have read this [tweet](https://twitter.com/nixcraft/status/234569703715135488), but can't figure out what is the meaning of this statement:

```
grep --color [Cat] <<<"nixCraft"
```

After executing this statement, it outputs:

```
[root@localhost command]# grep --color [Cat] <<<"nixCraft"
nixCraft
```

Only the letter `a` is in red-color.

I have referred the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings), but can't understand why only `a` is colored. Could anyone explain this statement? Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Did you type it in right? The C, a, and t should all be colored.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: Yes, it is only `a` colored.Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I ran it and all three letters are colored, much like in @paxdiablo's answer. Something weird with your `grep`, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[Cat]` denotes a filename-expansion — it will match any file whose name is `C`, `a`, or `t`. In your case, it appears that you have a file named `a`, so your command expands to:

```
grep --color a <<<"nixCraft"
```

Note that if no filenames matched that pattern, then filename-expansion would fail, and the behavior would depend on Bash settings. The default behavior in that case is to pass it through to the command as an argument, such that your command would effectively be

```
grep --color '[Cat]' <<<"nixCraft"
```

and all three of those letters would be colored. If that's actually the behavior you *want* — if you *want* all three of those letters to be matched — then you should use `'[Cat]'` (with quotes) rather than `[Cat]` in your Bash command.

Comment: Yeah, there is a file `a` in the directory. After removing it, it works! Thanks!

Comment: @NanXiao, just be aware the removing the file _isn't_ the fix. Quoting the regex is.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it works as expected:

[image]

However, because you've used a "naked" pattern `[Cat]`, it's subject to filename expansion by the shell:

[image]

In that case, `bash` has interpreted `[Cat]` to mean any of the files `C`, `a`, or `t`. In the case above, only `a` exists so the command has become:

```
grep --color a <<<"nixCraft"
```

and that's why you're only seeing the `a` in red.

To fix this, just protect the pattern from the shell:

```
grep --color '[Cat]' <<<"nixCraft"
```